# How to turn off string concatenation optimization

Tags: java, jvm, concatenation, javac, string-concatenation

In Java 9 Oracle improved String concatenation. Now `"" + someBoolean` turns into `invokedynamic` with `StringConcatFabric.makeConcat` as bootstrap method. That fabric generates classes at runtime that concatenate your strings. I want to disable this behaviour and fallback to plain old string builder.
So I supposed that javac has flag that do what I want. But I can't find it.

Comment: Why would you want to turn it off?

Comment: Because I have to remove all runtime classes generation from our java fork.
It is because of our anticheat. We really don't have any other ways.

Comment: I guess you are referring to this change: [jep280](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/280)

Comment: @ЮрийБаринов so you’re also removing all JDK internal uses of lambda expressions, method references,  Reflection, and `Proxy`? No access to annotations allowed? Even the XML parsers/XSLT processors use runtime class generation and who knows what else uses it as well.

Comment: I generate Proxies and Lambdas at compile time. So we have no got problems with annotations and lambdas.
Reflection generates classes only after 5 calls to method so I just removed this functionality. But I generate accessors for some hardcoded methods.
And about XML. We just don't use XML parsers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two parts to the string concatenation feature.

1. **At runtime**

   In Java 9+, at runtime, String concatenation is controlled by the `StringConcatFactory` class ([javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/StringConcatFactory.html)). That's because `javac` generates `invokedynamic` bytecode to `StringConcatFactory::makeConcat` wherever String concatenation is needed.

   `StringConcatFactory` defines several strategies for **runtime** concatenation  in the form of a `Strategy` enum ([source code](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/687ce3e7bb6d45ef67037dd77acd58aa48bbd724/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/invoke/StringConcatFactory.java#L136)).

   You can change the default strategy from the command line by setting `-Djava.lang.invoke.stringConcat`

   To get the Java-8 behavior at runtime, you need to set it to `BC_SB`, which stands for "Bytecode, StringBuilder"

   Here are the other values, for completeness:

   ```
   /**
    * Bytecode generator, calling into {@link java.lang.StringBuilder}.
    */
   BC_SB,

   /**
    * Bytecode generator, calling into {@link java.lang.StringBuilder};
    * but trying to estimate the required storage.
    */
   BC_SB_SIZED,

   /**
    * Bytecode generator, calling into {@link java.lang.StringBuilder};
    * but computing the required storage exactly.
    */
   BC_SB_SIZED_EXACT,

   /**
    * MethodHandle-based generator, that in the end calls into {@link java.lang.StringBuilder}.
    * This strategy also tries to estimate the required storage.
    */
   MH_SB_SIZED,

   /**
    * MethodHandle-based generator, that in the end calls into {@link java.lang.StringBuilder}.
    * This strategy also estimate the required storage exactly.
    */
   MH_SB_SIZED_EXACT,

   /**
    * MethodHandle-based generator, that constructs its own byte[] array from
    * the arguments. It computes the required storage exactly.
    */
   MH_INLINE_SIZED_EXACT
   ```
2. **At compile time**

   As Kayaman correctly notes, the `StringConcatFactory` affects the program at **runtime** only. The bytecode will still contain an `invokedynamic` to `StringConcatFactory` wherever Strings are concatenated. There are several ways of getting back the calls to `StringBuilder`:

   - The most straightforward approach of disabling this behavior is to pass the `--release=8` flag to javac to force the generation of Java-8 compatible code. However, this affects not only string concatenation.
   - A more targeted option is to control concatenation specifically, by passing `-XDstringConcat=inline`.

     Let's take this piece of code as an example:

     ```
     public class Print {    
         public static void main(String[] args) {
             String foo = "a";
             String bar = "b";
             System.out.println(foo+bar);
         }
     }
     ```

     If we compile it without any flags, we'll get:

     ```
     public class Print {
       public Print();
         Code:
            0: aload_0
            1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
            4: return

       public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
         Code:
            0: ldc           #2                  // String a
            2: astore_1
            3: ldc           #3                  // String b
            5: astore_2
            6: getstatic     #4                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
            9: aload_1
           10: aload_2
           11: invokedynamic #5,  0              // InvokeDynamic #0:makeConcatWithConstants:(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
           16: invokevirtual #6                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
           19: return
     }
     ```

     Note the `invokedynamic` to `makeConcatWithConstants`.

     However, if we run `javac -XDstringConcat=inline Print.java`, we'll get this:

     ```
     public class Print {
       public Print();
         Code:
            0: aload_0
            1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
            4: return

       public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
         Code:
            0: ldc           #2                  // String a
            2: astore_1
            3: ldc           #3                  // String b
            5: astore_2
            6: getstatic     #4                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
            9: new           #5                  // class java/lang/StringBuilder
           12: dup
           13: invokespecial #6                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":()V
           16: aload_1
           17: invokevirtual #7                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
           20: aload_2
           21: invokevirtual #7                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
           24: invokevirtual #8                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
           27: invokevirtual #9                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
           30: return
     }
     ```

     Here the `String` concatenation is done using the `StringBuilder`, just like in Java 8.

Answer (score 1):

As of Java 15, `StringConcatFactory` provides no other strategies for concatenation than `MH_INLINE_SIZED_EXACT`. See [this thread](https://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2020-May/066608.html) in the mailing lists and [this bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8245455) for details.

As Malt has already pointed out in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58681713/8130293), you can now only get back to `StringBuilder`s by disabling use of `invokedynamic` at compile time. To do this, pass the `-XDstringConcat=inline` flag to the compiler. More details in the above referenced Malt's answer.

If working with JAR files from Maven Central, [you will need to recompile them yourself](https://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2020-May/066614.html).